# ModX Revo Как открывается форма обратной связи?

Tags: modx

Имеется сайт на MODX Revolution 2.8.3-pl.
Идет второй день моего знакомства с MODX. Возник вопрос: каким образом осуществляется вызов формы обратной связи?

Код ссылки на кнопку вызова:
`<a class="section_form_btn open_feedback_form" href="#">ПОЗВОНИТЕ МНЕ</a>`

Вызывается форма Чанк: feedback_form (80)

Т.е. насколько я понимаю аргумент "open_feedback_form" в "class" как то влияет на это? Мне необходимо вызвать другую форму. Какова логика этого в MODX?

Answer (score 0):

Ищите код Javascript, который воспринимает клик на элементе c классом `section_form_btn open_feedback_form` и открывает форму(которая в чанке `feedback_form`). Чтобы вывести другую форму создайте другой чанк с формой, выведите его на той же странице, поправьте код JS, чтобы отображал по клику новую форму.